# I used Vuei18n for translation in vue. Static words come backend by axios. But VueI18n is not waiting axios and messages are empty

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vue-i18n

/*VueI18n is not waiting loadLocaleMessages() */

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import axios from 'axios'
import  API  from '@/store/config.js'
Vue.use(VueI18n)

```
const messages = {}
let lang = localStorage.getItem('lang')
 function loadLocaleMessages() {
     axios.get(API + 'translation?_l='+lang)
    .then(response => {
        messages[lang] = response.data.data
    })
    return messages
}

 function createMissingMessages(locale, key, vm, values) {
        console.log(lang in messages);
        axios.post(API + "translation/create", {"message": key})
        console.log(vm,values)
     
}

export default new VueI18n({
        locale: 'ru',
        fallbackLocale: 'ru',
        messages: loadLocaleMessages(),
        missing:  (locale, key, vm, values) =>  createMissingMessages(locale, key, vm, values)
    })
```

Comment: This one may be useful: https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/lazy-loading.html

Comment: I have been tried it :(

Comment: Why don't you have your JSONs as static assets in your project btw ? Usually you do fetch those at build time from an API, not on runtime. I can you can try to wrap your whole setup into an iife and await it.

Comment: thanks,   it was useful  https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/lazy-loading.html for me